# Can you "text to column" 3 specific bits of data from one cell into 3 cells

Tags: google-sheets, text-formatting

I am trying to find a way to split the numbers from a cell with the following data in it:

31(3)/22

With this data in a cell, in the adjacent 3 cells, I would like to see the results returned as thus
31 3 22

I have tried to use `=iferror(arrayformula(split(D2:D,"(")),"")` but obviously I have to do this 5 times which takes up multiple extra lines. I would then plan to fill the column to cover over 10,000 lines (possibly).

Any ideas? Is there a way of building multiple array formulae in one go?

Answer (score 1):

One can extract multiple parts of a string with regexextract, for example

```
=arrayformula(iferror(regexextract(D2:D, "(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)")))
```

expects each string to contain three groups of digits, separated by non-digits, and places these groups in separate columns.  So, `31(3)/22` becomes three entries: 33, 3, 22.

Notation: `\d` a digit; `\d+` a group of 1+ digits; `\D` same for non-digits; `()` capturing parentheses: return the group of symbols within.

A more forgiving form of the regex is

```
=arrayformula(iferror(regexextract(D2:D, "(\d*)\D*(\d*)\D*(\d*)")))
```

which allows some groups to be empty: e.g., it will also split 34(22) to 34 22.